# Reading different files in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter. Just a beginner.

I wanted to make an E- reader for Android. Which can view epub, pdf, fb2 etc. files.

What I have done so far:

I have used a package called "advanced pdf reader" from pub.dev then open a pdf file from URL only. Can't load pdf from my storage.

Asking for suggestions:

How can I read different files (pdf+ epub+fb2 etc) from my App? UI should be same for every files.
How do I make this? Do I need to use different packages? If yes, how do I make same UI for each files?

Comment: You can search for dependencies and use the most appropriate ones for your project, but if you feel like different dependencies generate different user interfaces then you can simply get into the dependency files and style it at your own choice. 

Editing files of the dependencies you have integrated to your app it is a possibility in Flutter.

Comment: There are many open source document viewers ( like: okular, poppler, libepub etc) available in GitHub written in C/C++. Is it possible to use them in my App? Using dart ffi for C & C++  or any other way?I just wanted to read files using their code.

Answer (score 0):

So for starters, i don't think there's a package on pub.dev that can allow you to read pdf, epub e.t.c at once. So what i suggest you do is that you work first on your app supporting pdf, for that you can use this package known as [Syncfusion_pdf_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer), you can check out the syncfusion website for more information. I believe that epub support is limited at the moment for flutter. But you can check out this package for epub suppport [epub_viewer](https://pub.dev/packages/epub_view).